# about linux module printk

Tags: c, linux, module

I write a module,and want add it to kernel.It will print a world when i insmod the module.but it will not...

the module as:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>

static int __init hello_init()
{
    printk(KERN_EMERG"Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}

static void __exit hello_exit()
{
    printk("<6>hello exit\n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

why the "Hello World!\n" dose not print when i load the module??
Are there some one meet the question? thinks for your help....

Comment: Have you look into the logfiles or check with dmesg-command?

Comment: I can see the worlds in dmesg,the problem is that it cann't print on screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't get a compile/linking error and `insmod`/`modprobe` didn't complain about missing symbols, there are two reasons why this can happen:

1. Someone defined a macro `printk()`
2. You looked in the wrong place. The text will be printed to the syslog. To see that, use `dmesg | tail`

Comment: But someone say if add high priority as 'KERN_EMERG' or 'KERN_ALERT' before the world of print,it may print on  screen.I don't understand this,can you tell me?thanks....

Comment: That depends on your system's configuration. High levels get printed on the "console". Usually that is tty0 (i.e. the text mode console which you get with Ctrl+Alt+F1) but on OpenSUSE, it's tty10.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's a linking or a header problem.

It seems you haven't specified any license, too, which can be a problem.

You can try this [site](http://blog.markloiseau.com/2012/04/hello-world-loadable-kernel-module-tutorial/), especially about the linking and loading part.

Comment: I am sorry for i can't get the print worlds on screen by the example i get from the site you gave.I still don't know what's wrong.